# Why couldn't Julia superset python?

Tags: python, julia, language-design

The Julia Language syntax looks very similar to python, while the concept of a class (if one should address it as such a thing) is more what you use in C. There were many reasons why the creators decided on the difference with respect to the OOP. Still would it have been so hard (in comparison to create Julia in first place which is impressive) to find some canonical way to interpret python to Julia and thus get a hold of all the python libraries?

Comment: I suppose that Julia does look similar to Python, although there are important differences (I don't think whitespace has any semantic content in Julia). But it's sufficiently different that I don't think it could really be a superset. I mean, not even C++ is a true superset of C, and the syntax is way more similar between those two than between Python and Julia...

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based, because while I believe the answer is "yes, it would have been both difficult and limiting", it's not the sort of concretely-answerable-with-some-code question SO is best at.

Comment: Where would you suggest to move the question?

Comment: @DSM no this is not opinion-based, there are very clear reasons in the design of the type system why it could not have happened. The question "why couldn't Julia superset Python's syntax" is opinion-based, but why the language itself in design and implementation could not superset Python is clearly due to type inferrability since a lot of Julia is doing is just provably not possible with what Python allows.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas: if you'd prefer either too broad or off-topic, that would work too, but consensus on Meta was not to spend too much time worrying about _which_ close reason you go with if several are defensible.

Comment: It's tagged as language design, so I don't see it as off-topic. And it's not broad either: it's a very simple and pointed question about why Julia is not just Python with a JIT. This is a question which comes up quite a bit and it's a very specific question which has a very specific answer.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas: life is too short.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. The design of Python makes it fundamentally difficult to optimize at compile-time (i.e. before you run the code). It is simply false that Julia is fast BECAUSE of its JIT. Rather, Julia is designed with its type system and multiple dispatch in mind so that way the compiler can know all of the necessary details to compile "the same code you would have written in C". That's what makes it fast: the type system. It makes a few trade-offs that allow it to, in "type-stable" functions, fully deduce what the types of every variable is, know what the memory layout of the type should be (including parametric types, so `Vector{Float64}` has a memory layout which is determined by the type and its parameter which inlines `Float64` values like a NumPy array, except this is generalized in a way that your own `struct` types get the same efficiency), and compile a version of the code specifically for the types which are seen.

There are many ways where this is at odds with Python. For example, if the number of fields in a struct could change, then the memory layout could not be determined and thus these optimizations cannot occur at "compile-time". Julia was painstakingly designed to make sure that it would have type inferrability, and it uses that to generate code which is fully typed and remove all runtime checks (in type-stable functions. When a function is not type-stable, the types of the variables become dynamic rather than static and it slows down to Python-like speeds). In this sense, Julia actually isn't even optimized yet: all of its performance comes "for free" given the design of its type system. Python/MATLAB/R has to try really hard to optimize at runtime because it doesn't have the capability to do these deductions. In fact, those languages are "better optimized" right now in terms of runtime optimizations, but no one has really worked on runtime optimizations in Julia yet because in most performance sensitive cases you can get it all at compile time.

So then, what about Numba? Numba tries to take the route that Julia takes but with Python code by limiting what can be done so that way it can get type-stable code and compile that efficiently. However, this means a few things. First of all, it's not compatible with all Python codes or libraries. But more importantly, since Python is not a language built around its type system, the tools for controlling the code at the level of types is much reduced. So Numba doesn't have parametric vectors and generic codes which auto-specialize via multiple dispatch because these aren't features of the language. But that also means that it cannot make full use of the design, which limits how much it can do. It can handle the "use only floating point array" stuff just fine, but you can see it gets limited if you want one code to produce efficient code for "any number type, even ones I don't know about". However, by design, Julia does this automatically.

So at the core, Julia and Python are extremely different languages. It can be hard to see because Julia's syntax is close to Python's syntax, but they do not work the same at all.

This is a short summary of what I have described in a few blog posts. These go into more detail and show you how Julia is actually generating efficient code, how it gives you a generic "Python looking style" but doing so with full inferrability all the way down, and what the tradeoffs are.

How type-stability plus multiple dispatch gives performance:

http://ucidatascienceinitiative.github.io/IntroToJulia/Html/WhyJulia
http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/7-julia-gotchas-handle/

How the type system allows for highly performant generic designs

http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/type-dispatch-design-post-object-oriented-programming-julia/

Comment: See also [this answer](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-motivation-why-werent-numpy-scipy-numba-good-enough/2236/10) in a recent discussion thread about the motivations for Julia.